# SAPUI5 - Eclipse file not saved

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sapui5

I'm new to SAPUI5. Initially I'm working with My Fiori APP.

I have downloaded this project form this URL: http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/index?rid=/library/uuid/60668332-b85d-3110-3fb7-8133d856d3e5

Now I'm trying to edit this file as my convenience, Now a time I got an error as **Save coulde not be completed**. I tried a lot to solve this problem. But Same issues repeated.

Please anyone help me to solve this Error.

[image: Save Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with UI5 or Eclipse. Check the following?
- do you have write permission in the folder?
- do you have write permission for the file?

Just make a right click on the folder/file, choose "Properties"  and check for "Read-Only" flag...

Comment: Hi Nabi. Thanks.. Yep Read-Only flag has been set to all folder. I didn't watch it. Once again thanks Nabi to find out problem.